# Не правильно передаётся переменная Java

Tags: java

Помогите разобраться. в методе `send` , значение `numberS` генерируется, как мне нужно. но при переходе в метод `onUpdateReceived` переменная принимает последнее значение массива. Как мне получить то значение, которое имеется в методе `send` .

```
public void send(){
String[] greportsArr = new String[greportsL.size()];
greportsArr = greportsL.toArray(greportsArr);
for(int i = 0; i < numL.size(); i++){
    numberL = numL.get(i);
    String reportsL = greportsArr[i];
    String[] numLArr = new String[numL.size()];
    numLArr = numL.toArray(numLArr);
    numberS = numLArr[i];
for(int it = 0; it < userids.size(); it++){
    String userid = userids.get(it);        
  ------
inlineKeyboardButton1.setText(numberS);
inlineKeyboardButton1.setCallbackData("Agree");
----
System.out.println(numberS);  // тут значение еще верное

try {
   execute(message);
} catch (TelegramApiException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}   }
   }


public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
----
} else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
        String call_data = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();
    long message_id = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getMessageId();
    long chat_id = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId();
    System.out.println(numberS);   // тут уже приходит последнее значение в массиве.
    if (call_data.equals("Agree")) {
        Login lgc = new Login();
         lgc.updateQ(numberS);
            String answer = "Согласовано";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну по данному коду определить почему не совсем так как вы хотите не удастся.

Вы меняете

```
 numberS = numLArr[i]
```

На каждой итерации цикла. Понятно что при завершении цикла вы получите последний элемент массива.

Проверьте значение вашей переменной после цикла.

```
System.out.println(numberS);
```

Comment: да, сразу после цикла тоже значение уже не то, что нужно
как тогда быть, я бы мог вызывать нужный мне номер из массива имея номер, по которому проходится цикл, а как тогда мне этот номер получить? в данном случае это нужно значение переменной i, но в другом методе? или я не так понял

Comment: На самом деле у вас отдельная переменная.  numberS Если вам нужно чтоб после присваивания значения в цикле оно не менялось ставьте условия.

Comment: как я могу это сделать? использовать while во втором методе?

Comment: Зачем while? Просто добавьте условие при котором numberS = numLArr[i] не будет выполняться. if (condition ....) numberS = numLArr[i];

Comment: понял, спасибо
вроде получается